# Expected runtime for hashing with a binary search tree as collision handling

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, binary-trees, hash

I thought about implementing a data structure with expected runtime of O(1) for insertion, deletion and look-up and a worst case runtime for these operations of O(log(n)). This is under the assumption of uniformly distributed data.

What I thought of was a simple hash table using BST for the collisions. Does that make sense or is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello @JakobRainer, welcome to stack exchange! Note that a simple BST is worst-case O(n), so you would need some kind of self-balancing BST.

Comment: The title reads `Expected runtime`, the body `worst case runtime`. `using BST for the collisions` Does *one per table* make a difference compared to *one per bucket*?